# Resolved: Wrong path cbbackup accu/diff

Tags: couchbase

I make my backup with the following command line in Jenkins. In my Jenkins I can choose several bucket at the same times. When I start my job with many bucket, he starts them one by one.

`/opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup {{ ip }} {{ couchbase_backup_dir }} --username={{ couchbase_admin }} --password={{ couchbase_password }} --mode={{ couchbase_backup_mode }} --verbose`

When I set {{ couchbase_backup_mode }} to "full" there is no problem.

./{{ couchbase_backup_dir }}/1st_backup/1st_backup-full/bucket_full and ./{{ couchbase_backup_dir }}/2nd_backup/2nd_backup-full/bucket_full

After that I want accu backups so I start the same processus but I set {{ couchbase_backup_mode }} to "accu"

The first bucket backup "accu" is in ./{{ couchbase_backup_dir }}/2nd_backup/2nd_backup-full/bucket_accu when he should be in ./{{ couchbase_backup_dir }}/1st_backup/1st_backup-accu/bucket_accu

The second bucket backup is in ./{{ couchbase_backup_dir }}/2nd_backup/2nd_backup-accu/bucket_accu

So why my first accu backup are in the wrong directory. thanks

Comment: [Resolved] In fact when I run the backup, I tell it to make the full of bucket 1 in a directory that is created with a certain name. So full backups are not mixed together. When I run a accu backup of bucket 1 I tell him to put himself in the same directory as that he necessarily does in relation to him.

Comment: Exemple: bucket1:
backup/dev-produits/2020-XX-XX/2020-XX-XX-full/bucket-dev-produits
backup/dev-produits/2020-XX-XX/2020-XX-XX-accu(ou diff)/bucket-dev-produits (edited) 
3:06
bucket 2 :
backup/dev-companies/2020-XX-XX/2020-XX-XX-full/bucket-dev-companies
backup/dev-companies/2020-XX-XX/2020-XX-XX-accu ou diff/bucket-dev-companies